# Use KeyVault in Azure Functions local development

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am using `TypeScript` for Azure Functions development. On production I use `@Microsoft.KeyVault` to read the secrets from a KeyVault. Is there a way I can make it work in local development as well?

I am thinking there might be a way to register the VS Code instance/certificate in Azure AD and KeyVault and somehow work it out.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have been discussed a long time ago. From various perspectives, the official seems not to provide a way to use `key vault` directly locally.

But you can still refer to some discussions on this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3907)：

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you any best practices about how to share local configuration with other developers in team?

Comment: Local development using `GitHub` and `SVN` shared configuration files is a good solution.

Comment: I did not get it. I have secrets in configs and need to protect them. How does `GitHub` help with that?

Comment: Tried the above, and no dice. cant use the keyvault locally.